# How to call a prototyped function from within the prototyped "class"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, function, prototype

```
function FakeClass(){};  
FakeClass.prototype.someMethod = function(){};
FakeClass.prototype.otherMethod = function(){
    //need to call someMethod() here.
}
```

I need to call someMethod from otherMethod, but apparently it doesn't work. If i build it as a single function (not prototyped), i can call it, but calling a prototyped does not work. How can i do it as if i was treating the function just like a class method?

**Update:**
I'm calling the method after a jQuery event is triggered. Does it affect the way the whole thing behaves?

```
function CicloviarioEngine(){};

CicloviarioEngine.prototype.test = function(){
    alert("Hey");
}
CicloviarioEngine.prototype.initialize = function(){
    $('#add-route').click(function(){
    this.test(); //doesn't work
    CicloviarioEngine.test(); //doesn't work
    externalTest(); //works 

    });
}

function externalTest(){
    alert("externalTest()");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside the event handler function is not the same as `this` in the enclosing `initialize` function (in fact it will be a reference to the element that has been clicked). The easiest way to deal with this is to save the value of `this` into a variable, which the event handler will have access to from its enclosing scope:

```
CicloviarioEngine.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#add-route').click(function(){
        that.test();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The members of the prototype will be available on the object instance, so you can simply call the method using the `this` keyword:

```
FakeClass.prototype.otherMethod = function(){
  this.someMethod();
};
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/oneme/2).

Comment: I updated the question... i forgot to mention the jQuery part, sorry. :)